# Property reference exception with jpa

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller

I am new to spring data jpa and  trying to use it but facing an issue with org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property name found for type User!
    Could some one suggest me what can be done ? I am struggling but could not find an solution for this

```
**Service**
public interface UserService {
        Page<User> findAllUsers(); 
    }

**Service Impl** where I am trying to implement the service methods            
@Service("userService")
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
    /*@Autowired*/
    @Qualifier("userDao")
    private  final UserDao dao;

        @Autowired
        public UserServiceImpl(UserDao dao) {
            this.dao = dao;
        }
        private static final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

        private static List<User> users;
                public Page<User> findAllUsers() {
                        return dao.findAll(pageRequest);
                }

**DAO**
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long>  {
}

**User**    

      @Entity
            @Table(name="USERAG")
            public class User implements Serializable {
                @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "users_seq")
                        private long id;

                @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = true)
                private String username;

                @Column(name = "ADDRESS", nullable = true)
                private String address;

                @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = true)
                private String email;
```

Comment: What does your User entity look like?  Does it have a property "name" on it?

Comment: sorry forget to add, add now please check @Brian Kates, yes it has username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you removed your DAO method.  I seem to recall that you had a order on "name".  Your entity does not have "name", rather it has "username".  In short, it's looking for "name" on your entity (which you do not have)

Comment: i tried to comment the username and try with other still it did not work. do you want me to create a attribute name ?

Comment: Show me your DAO method again

Comment: username to name did the trick, i think i should name according to table column.